# Extended class instance cannot access the injected properties of the parent

Tags: php

```
class dog {

    public $id = 0;
    public function __construct($attributes = array()) {

        foreach($attributes as $field=>$value){
          $this->$field = $value;
        }

    }
}

$data = array('id' => 123);
$dog = new dog($data);

class poodle extends dog {

}

$poodle = new poodle();

var_dump($poodle->id);
```

The var_dump gives 0 rather than 123. This is toy code rather than the real code so there may be some syntax errors but should illustrate my problem.

As a side note I am keeping things public rather than protected for easy access directly rather than having to setup 50+ getters and because no validation is required on the properties and no other code will ever change them once they are set.

Comment: Why would you expect the var_dump to give you 123? You create an instance of your `dog` class and set that instance's ID; when you create your `poodle`, it's a completely separate object, and any changes you make to the one won't affect the other.

Comment: @andrewsi I see. In that case, can you please recommend how I should be architecting my approach with classes so that poodle can access 123? After I have initialised dog via dependency injection, I want any instances that are class extensions of dog to be able to access the updates properties e.g. 123, rather than the original ones.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't do that directly by extending a class - objects are instantiated separately, so a change to one's properties won't be picked up by another. I think you can do it by using instantiating your `dog` object first, and then passing that object into the other objects. For example, you can create a `database` object, and pass that into a `user` object, that can then use that to query the database.

Comment: @andrewsi your comment should actually be an answer.

Comment: @asymmetric - it did rather get away from me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding how objects work.

```
class dog {

    public $id = 0;
    public function __construct($attributes = array()) {

        foreach($attributes as $field=>$value){
          $this->$field = $value;
        }

    }
}

class poodle extends dog {
}
```

When I call the construct on the `dog` class, I get a `dog` object; that is a stand-along variable, complete in itself. If I then create a `poodle` object, that is a new and separate object. The class is basically a blueprint to show what the object will look like when it's created - by the time you're making changes to the values of an object, you can't then change the class itself.

For what you want to do, you'll have to approach it a different way - you can't set a value in one object and then be able to access that in a different object. Instead, something like:

```
class DB {
    public function __construct($attributes) {
        // set up database connection here
    }
}

class User {
    public $DB;

    public function __construct ($DB) {
        $this->DB = $DB;
    }
}

$myDB = new DB();
$myUser = new User($DB);
```

That lets you set up a single database class, that you can pass into a second object; changes made in your database object will filter through into your Users

Comment: The relation between User and DB is dependency injection - call constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the parent's construct to your extended class.

```
 class poodle extends dog {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately when I try it in my code. It still gives 0 rather than 123.

Answer (score 0):

> poodle extends from dog then poodle is a dog too. $poodle = new poodle() is to create new object, then it always returns Zero for id attribute because it is new object.

Try with:

```
$data = array('id' => 123);
$dog = new dog($data);
var_dump($poodle->id);

$poodle = new poodle($data);
var_dump($poodle->id);
```